# « To deliver a line » en français

Tags: expressions, traduction

J'écris un commentaire et suis coincé sur une phrase que je n'arrive pas à bien formuler en français:

> Orwell delivers one of the most powerful lines in modern literature

Je suis bloqué sur la traduction de « to deliver a line », dans un sens proche de « assener une phrase », mais ça sonne bizarre.

(Pour le contexte, je parle de la dernière phrase de 1984 de Orwell, « Il aimait Big Brother ».)

Comment: 'Deliver' est un choix étrange à l'écrit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voici ce que j'écrirais :

> Orwell rédige l'une des phrases les plus marquantes de la littérature contemporaine.

There is no need to try to stick too closely to the original wording when translating a text. While *livrer* or *délivrer* can certainly translate *deliver*, it doesn't seem a good match here. There is nothing really delivered. Orwell wrote a line, he didn't share his thoughts or something (*livrer ses pensées*).

-- off-topic --

There are also a few words that deserve a better translation.

I suggest:

- *phrase* (sentence) for *line* because that's what it is. *Ligne* is a typographical kind of thing, not a literary one.
- *marquante* for powerful. *Puissante* is not wrong but doesn't go well with *phrase* (or *ligne*). *Marquante* seems to me closer to the intended meaning.
- *contemporaine* (contemporary) for modern. While both terms are relative to the time when they are used, Orwell wrote *1984* in 1948 which is inside the *littérature contemporaine* period commonly considered to begin after WWII. The *littérature moderne* is usually opposed to the *littérature classique* so span a wider period.

Comment: I strongly agree with this one.

Answer (score 1):

DeepL translator gives us the following;

> Orwell livre l'une des lignes les plus puissantes de la littérature moderne.

It seems however that its phrasing is not quite idiomatic and a variant of it appears more satisfactory;

> Orwell livre un énoncé des plus chargés en implications dans toute la littérature anglaise moderne.

(TLFi) c) [L'obj. désigne un inanimé abstr.] Confier. Livrer ses impressions, un secret. Certains (...) rougissaient de livrer leur préférence (LACRETELLE, Silbermann, 1922, p. 89). Marthe (...) ne livre qu'une faible part de ce qu'elle pense (BOSCO, Mas Théot., 1945, p. 343).

(Dictionnaire de l'Académie) : Fig. Je livre ces quelques phrases à votre méditation, à votre sagacité. Livrer ses pensées, ses espoirs, ses impressions, les faire connaître, les révéler.

The concept "faire part" can be added to the nuances found in those two dictionaries;

(TLFi) *faire part* 3. Faire part de qqc. à qqn. Faire connaître, informer de. Synon. communiquer, faire savoir*. Faire part de sa pensée, de son opinion, de ses projets à qqn

The following variant  would do also, as I see it; it seems that the added pronoun makes the critic's act of imparting this revelation sound more congenial, a more personal communication to the literary minded;

> Orwell nous livre un énoncé des plus chargés en implications dans toute la littérature anglaise moderne.

If the text is intended for a French speaking audience, as that seems very likely, it might be preferable to specify the scope of the literature  against which the statement is to be taken lest it be unclear that it would be European or even World literature. (Needless to say, in the translation, "anglaise" has been chosen as a mere possibility.)

Comment: @subsexdexter Cet usage a été vérifié dans le TLFi ; j'ai pensé qu'il convenait : c) [L'obj. désigne un inanimé abstr.] Confier. Livrer ses impressions, un secret. Certains (...) rougissaient de livrer leur préférence (LACRETELLE, Silbermann, 1922, p. 89). Marthe (...) ne livre qu'une faible part de ce qu'elle pense (BOSCO, Mas Théot., 1945, p. 343).

Comment: @subsexdexter Je crois, tout au contraire, que c'est ce qu'Orwell fait ; à l'appui de cette conviction citons le dictionnaire de l'académie, plus spécifique encore que le TLFi : « Fig. Je livre ces quelques phrases à votre méditation, à votre sagacité. Livrer ses pensées, ses espoirs, ses impressions, les faire connaître, les révéler. ».

Answer (score 1):

Juste une suggestion amusante, en profitant d'un autre sens du verbe *to deliver*, "accoucher", on peut alors jouer sur le sens figuré d'accoucher, qui est relativement courant pour décrire la production d'une oeuvre massive, très importante, ou ayant nécessité une longue préparation.

> Orwell **accouche** de l'une des phrases les plus marquantes de la littérature contemporaine.

C'est probablement trop imagé pour un commentaire d'histoire ou de politologie, mais n'est-on pas ici dans le domaine de la littérature ?

Comment: Le parallèle avec l'anglais est très bien trouvé, mais *accoucher* a, dans ce sens, souvent un sens plutôt péjoratif, où la chose accouchée est généralement décevante par rapport à l'effort (laborieux) fourni (*la montagne a accouché d'une souris*) qui, il me semble, ne va pas bien avec le sens de la phrase de la question.

Comment: @jiliagre C'est juste, j'avais aussi eu ce sentiment, mais le parallèle était trop beau pour ne pas être évoqué, ne serait-ce que pour enrichir les propositions.

Comment: On trouve l'image utilisée par Zola dans son  « accouchement du vrai » et elle est catégorisée par certains critiques littéraires anglais comme relevant du grandiloquent, opinion que je tends à partager bien que pas vraiment  sur la base d'une reconnaissance des limites permises dans l'expression imagée, ce problème-ci restant vaste et ouvert ; je ne me peux m'empêcher de croire à un certain mauvais gout en ce qui concerne cette utilisation.